# Não permitir alteração em código fonte

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, segurança, google-chrome

Alguém sabe como não permitir alteração em "values" pelo inspecionar elemento ?
ah uns dias atrás entrei em um site e fui tentar alterar o valor de uma input, mas quando cliquei ENTER pra gravar, automaticamente o valor da input voltou ao padrão do código mesmo..

Nas minhas aplicações testei fazer isso achando que era alguma função de proteção do chrome, mas não..

então se alguem sabe como aplicar essa função de se segurança em formulários e inputs, da um Help ai.. Obg!

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível bloquear isso. O que você pode fazer é armazenar todo o código em uma variável e utilizar a função `setInterval` para verificar se o conteúdo foi modificado, porém isso pode causar conflitos com alguns plugins, por exemplo *Slideshows*.

Esses plugins altera o código padrão do site e nesse caso, não funcionaria corretamente esse método.

Mas... Segue um exemplo de código.

```js
const sourceCode = document.body.outerHTML;

setInterval( () => {
  
  if (sourceCode !== document.body.outerHTML) {
    document.body.innerHTML = sourceCode;
  }
  
}, 500);
```

```html
<h1>Tente alterar esse conteúdo via inspetor de elemento</h1>
```

Mas obviamente isso não é perfeito e pode ser facilmente burlado. Seja bloqueando o JavaScript no navegador ou degubando o código e removendo esse trecho.

> Isso também aumenta o consumo de memória.

Há outras coisas também como bloquear as teclas e o botão direito do mouse, por exemplo.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", ev => {
  switch( true ) {
    /* Previne F12 */
    case ev.keyCode === 123:
    
    /* Previne Ctrl + Shift +  */
    case ev.ctrlKey && ev.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 74:
    
    /* Previne Ctrl + U */
    case ev.ctrlKey && ev.keyCode == 85:
      console.log("Tecla bloqueada");
      ev.preventDefault();
      return false;
  }
})

/* Previne clique direito do mouse */
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

---

Além das formas já citadas, você também pode utilizar o `MutationObserver`. Com essa API você poderá monitorar os elementos que desejar.

Para utilizar essa classe, basta instancia-la, usando uma função de *callback*, e utilizar o método `observe` para iniciar o procedimento.

No método `observe`, podemos utilizar passar dois parâmetros: elemento e as opções que desejamos monitorar.

As opções disponíveis são:

- `childList`: Monitora adições e remoções dos elementos filho do elemento passado;
- `attributes`: Monitora alterações nos atributos do elemento passado;
- `characterData`: Monitora as alterações nos dados do elemento;
- `subtree`: Monitora os elementos filhos;
- `attributeOldValue`: Informa se deseja passar o valor antigo na função de *callback*;
- `characterDataOldValue`: Define *true* se `characterData` receber true e os dados do alvo antes que a mutação precise ser gravada;
- `attributeFilter`: Defina um *array* dos atributos locais (sem *namespace*), se não, todos os atributos serão monitoras.

  > Todas as opções, exceto `attributeFilter`, recebem um valor booleano.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function observe(element) {
  const node = element.outerHTML;

  new MutationObserver(event => {
    element.outerHTML = node;
  }).observe(element, {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributeOldValue: true,
    characterDataOldValue: true
  })
}

observe(document.querySelector("h1"));
```

```html
<h1>Tente alterar o elemento
  <code>&lt;h1&gt;</code>, via inspetor de elementos.</h1>
```

Dessa forma, a função irá monitorar todos os eventos que ocorrer no objeto `h1`

Comment: Ótimo Valdeir! Adorei nem pensei nessa questão kk claro
mas com base no meu código, o foco é evitar alterações apenas nos inputs, e todos eles veem do javascript ou seja esse código é perfeito pois se bloquear o script para tentar burlar então os inputs não vão aparecer.. 
claro que é burlável de qualquer forma , mas é isso mesmo que eu precisava.. Obrigado !

Comment: @DiMaxDeveloper Tranquilo. Se possível marca como resolvida para outros que tenham o mesmo problema, possam achar a pergunta mais facilmente.

Comment: E o motivo do `downvote`?

Comment: O código mais clean que vi é a segunda opção, de bloquear o click do mouse direito ou F12... Uma pena que podemos acessar o developer tools pelo menu do chrome ou apertando Ctrl + Shift + i